# Here i have wrote a code for getting the form data and storing the input in query but i got an error as TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, json, mongodb, mongodb-query, yaml

Here i have wrote a code for getting the form data using flask, i should get the input from yaml file and use it in mongo query without hardcoding, but the below code gives me an error as unhashable type:dict.

```
def files():
     first = request.form.get('name')
     sec = request.form.get('email')
     with open("query.yaml", "r") as f:
        try:
            data = yaml.load(f)
        except yaml.YAMLError as e:
            print(e)

    file = data["andfilter"]
    show = data["display"]
    file["Name"] = first
    file["Email"] = sec
    with open("query.yaml", 'w') as outfile:
        yaml.dump(data, stream=outfile, default_flow_style=False, indent=3)
    que1 = db.data.find({"$and":[file]},{show}) ########getting the error here
    resp = dumps(que1)
    select = pd.read_json(resp)
    return render_template('view.html', tables=[select.to_html(classes='info')],
```

```
qyery.yaml
andfilter:
   Name : bob
   Email: xyz@gmail.com
   
display:
   Name: 1
   Email: 1
   contact: 1
   _id: 0
```

Comment: Please, show [mre] (i.e. no need for flask part, etc.) as well as full traceback you get. What is `dumps`?

Comment: mongodumps from mongodb package

Comment: I don't know mongodb so I can't tell you how to achieve what you want but the error is `{show}`. `show` is a dict and you're trying to put it into a set. You can't do that because a dict is not hashable.

Comment: yes it worked thank you